# SSH freezes at pledge: network

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I setup passwordless ssh login. I could connect through ssh and also used sftp. suddenly I could not connect any more and ssh freezed.

- Server: Ubuntu 16.04
- Client: Ubuntu 18.04

`ssh --vvv user@host` freezes at **pledge: network**

```
...
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:w7sj+s08FJPpL09IVtmXmGZOUgxVHGcgpjCL3vxzSaQ
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:w7sj+s08FJPpL09IVtmXmGZOUgxVHGcgpjCL3vxzSaQ
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <host> ([<IP>]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
Timeout, server <host> not responding.
```

Before this happens, I started another ssh on the same host with same user and it freezed at sign_and_send_pubkey so I started the previously said ssh.

```
...
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:w7sj+s08FJPpL09IVtmXmGZOUgxVHGcgpjCL3vxzSaQ
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:w7sj+s08FJPpL09IVtmXmGZOUgxVHGcgpjCL3vxzSaQ
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection to <IP> port 22 timed out
```

- I tried reinstalling openssh-server from server and ssh from client. also restarted both of them (Server and client computer).
- Also tried to force connecting by password. It just changed the line `Authentication succeeded (password)` at output.
- Somebody said set `UsePAM no`, It did not work.
- Tried by `-o IPQoS=0` and had the same output.

At server recorded these at **syslog**:

```
...
May  7 07:26:10 host systemd[1]: Started Session c103 of user <user>.
May  7 07:26:10 host systemd[1]: Started Session c104 of user <user>.
May  7 07:26:26 host systemd[1]: Started Session 47 of user <user>.
May  7 07:26:33 host systemd[1]: Started Session 48 of user <user>.
```

I think this problem is from client. Because my friend could connect to server from his own computer.

Comment: Have you tried adding a further debug level (`ssh -vvv`) to see what (if any) packet-level transactions occur after that?

Comment: @steeldriver I checked as you said and it sent three same packets of type 80 (added to question). then timed out.

Comment: See if the proposed solution here helps: [SSH does not respond only from Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303579/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver Tried. Did not work. The same output.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your SSH connections it's better to view `/var/log/auth.log`.

i.e.

```
sudo tail -n 250 -f /var/log/auth.log
```

Your connection might be also filtered or blocked by tools like `fail2ban`.

Check if it's running on your server:

```
sudo ps ax | grep fail2ban
```

If it's present on your server, then by default it scans auth.log for failed login attempts and ban IP for 5 minutes.

If you don't have fail2ban make sure that there's nothing wrong with your network or firewall.

Use `dmesg` to read latest errors:

```
sudo dmesg -T
```

View your iptables rules with:

```
sudo iptables -nvL
```

and also check your interfaces for errors and overruns:

```
sudo ifconfig | grep errors
```

`ifconfig` is a part of net-tools, so make sure it's present on your Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was a crashed rsyslogd. I found this out because there were no more log entries in  /var/log/secure

So I Restarted service rsyslog restart resolved the problem for us.